# Resolve task. Extend current line and get value

Tags: c#, math, linear-equation

I'm looking for solve for this task in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).

There is an X and Y coordinate system.
The task is to [find the equation](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-2points.html) that matches the red line at the same angle and print the value of this line through the specified number of steps on the X scale.

Image below is an example of what I need to get. Given these points

- P1 (1/10)
- P2 (10/50)

[image: Example]

For example:

- What will be Y value when the X value will go to 20?
- How can I code it?

Also if you can, explain please the code. The problem is that line in task could be at random angle in each task.

Comment: please provide some code of your approaches to get better help with

Comment: I would love to, but unfortunately I'm only learning programming. I don't have any ideas how to do this :(

Comment: And what does your knowledge about straight lines in mathematics tell you? (or in [geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)))

Comment: Could you do this on a piece of paper? If not, it's not a programming problem. Computers cannot do magic. You will need to figure out how to do this yourself, only then can you come up with a way to make a computer do it.

Comment: I only know the equation of a line y = mx + c . But how to use in the code. I know that I need to use it to calculate the next value. But don't know how exactly

Comment: Do I need to calculate ratio between 50 & 10 ( divide 50/10 = 5 ) and then multiply result on the 20 (as in example). I will get value of 100. Is it that point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a *strait line*, you can put

```
private static Func<double, double> Linear(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
  if (x1 == x2) // Special case : vertical line
    if (y1 == y2)
      return (x) => y1 + x - x1;
    else
      return (x) => x == x1 ? 0.0 : double.NaN;
  else
    return (x) => y1 + (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) * (x - x1);
}
```

**Demo** (single point)

```
var func = Linear(1, 10, 10, 50);

Console.Write(func(20));
```

**Outcome:**

```
94.4444444444444
```

**Table:**

```
string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable
  .Range(0, 21)
  .Select(x => $"{x,2} : {func(x)}"));

Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
 0 : 5.55555555555556
 1 : 10               <- Given Point
 2 : 14.4444444444444
 3 : 18.8888888888889
 4 : 23.3333333333333
 5 : 27.7777777777778
 6 : 32.2222222222222
 7 : 36.6666666666667
 8 : 41.1111111111111
 9 : 45.5555555555556
10 : 50               <- Given Point
11 : 54.4444444444444
12 : 58.8888888888889
13 : 63.3333333333333
14 : 67.7777777777778
15 : 72.2222222222222
16 : 76.6666666666667
17 : 81.1111111111111
18 : 85.5555555555556
19 : 90
20 : 94.4444444444444 <- Required Point
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Equation of a line from 2 points](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-2points.html) the slope can be calcualted using

Slope m

```
m  =  (change in y) / (change in x)
m  =  (y2 − y1)     / (x2 − x1)
m  =  (50 - 10)     / (10 - 1) 
m =     40          / 9         = 40/9
```

The "point-slope" form of the equation of a straight line is

```
y − y1 = m(x − x1)  // we will use P1(1/10) with x1 = 1, y1 = 10
y - 10 = m(x - 1)
y      = m(x - 1) + 10
```

Test the equation with P2 (10/50)

```
50      = m(10-1) + 10  // y = 50 and x = 10
40      = m(9)
40/9    = m
```

To get a function that represents the equation (y = f(x))

```
y    = m(x - 1) + 10  // we know m = 40/9 and use f(x) instead of y
f(x) = 40/9(x - 1) + 10 
f(x) = (40/9)x - 40/9 + 90/9 
f(x) = (40/9)x + 90/9 - 40/9 
f(x) = (40/9)x + 50/9
```

Create a matching function

```cs
Func<decimal, decimal> lineEquation = (x) =>{
    return ((decimal)40/(decimal)9)*x + ((decimal)50/(decimal)9);
};
```

Test it in [linqpad](/questions/tagged/linqpad)

[image: Linqpad Demo]